# Trying to get JQ Roundabout to open link when in focus

Tags: jquery, html

Please could someone help me here with Freds JQ Roundabout.

I have a UL made up of several items which point to different pages on my site as so.

```
<ul>

    <li><a href="1.php">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="2.php">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="3.php">Page 3</a></li>

</ul>
```

I get these to apperar on my roundabout ok and it behaves as expected.

When I click on one of the items it comes into focus but what I would like to happen is once the animation has finished then the associated page opens. I believe this may have something to do with the clickToFocusCallback option but I dont know how to get the link from the href to open.Effectively I am looking for a function that will open the associated link when the child element becomes in focus.

I have created a function to bring up an alert when the child element comes in to focus and this seems to work ok but as I am totally new to all this I dont have a clue how I would get the link to open and have spent many nights reading possible solutions but dont have the knowledge to work them out.

Here are my roundabout settings

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#mainmenu ul').roundabout({
    tilt: -10,
    minScale: 1,
    minOpacity: 1,
    clickToFocusCallback: function test_link()
{
alert("Selected Item Is In Focus");
}

      });
   });

</script>
```

I am using the #mainmenu ul so it only picks up the UL in the div mainmenu as eventually I hope to have a sub menu as well which is also driven by Freds JQ roundabout.

This is my first post here so please be gentle and please let me know if I have not provided enough information.

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 0):

Have managed to resolve this one after a long night and lots of coffee

```
<li><a href="#" title="Home Page" onclick="$var='index.php'";return false;>Home Page</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="Page 2" onclick="$var='page2.php'";return false;>Page 2</a></li>}
```

and then my function

```
clickToFocusCallback: function (){
window.open(($var),"_self");
},
```